# How can we create an object of interface with Spring to autowire it but it's wrong to create the same object in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

Let's say we have an interface as "ABC.java"

```
interface ABC {
    public void hello();
}
```

Now we have a class like "ABCimpl.java"

```
public class ABCimpl implements ABC{
    
    @Override
    public void hello(){
         System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Now we have one more class named "DEFinpl.java"

```
public class DEFimpl{
    @Autowired
    ABC abc;

    public void trial(){
        abc.hello();
    }
}
```

but if we are simply using java we do not create an object for an interface. Why is that?
And what is happening here?

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I don't understand why java doesn't allow object creation of an interface but we can create an object of an interface when we use @Autowired annotation in spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot create an object of an interface in Java.

**Interfaces** in java can be defined as a full abstract class with **fields** (*public , static & final*) and empty methods (*public and abstract*). Although from Java 8 we can define default methods which can have their body and in Java 9 we can even have private methods.

*But the point is , in an interface we don't have fields present at the object level since all of them are by-default static. Hence its not logical or meaningful to have a constructor*

***which means --> No object creation.***

When we use spring **@Autowired** for initializing an interface , spring **does not** actually create an object of that interface rather an **object of its child class** is created.

In this case since only one child class exists for interface ABC which is class ABCImpl.

*So Spring will do something like this when we use **@Autowired** :*

```
ABC abc = new AbcImpl();
```

The abc is just a reference variable storing the object of child class (one of interface ABC implementation).
Things get interesting if we have multiple child classes and we use @Autowired. Then spring resolves this ambiguity by first checking the type and then name. If both are same then we can go for something like @Qualifier to add some additional tag to differentiate it.

Comment: Is this why we use @Qualifier while autowiring an abstract class object?

Comment: yes it is. @Satvik_08 please upvote the answer if your doubt is cleared.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer but it isn't showing as my reputation points are less

Comment: no problem. I'll wait for you to earn more reputation points ;) Cheers to learning :D

Comment: I've a spring project where I have repositories for data and I'm autowiring them in a controller class. Those repositories are interfaces and don't have any subclasses. How does spring then create those repositories' objects and autowire them?